# Apache Camel - Getting a list of files from FTP as a result of a GET request

Tags: rest, spring-boot, get, ftp, apache-camel

As the title suggests I'm trying to get a list of files from an FTP directory to send as a response of a GET request.

I have current rest route implementation:

```
rest().get("/files")
            .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .route()
            .routeId("restRouteId")
            .to("direct:getAllFiles");
```

On the other side of the direct route I have the following routes:

```
from("direct:getAllFiles")
            .routeId("filesDirectId")
            .to("controlbus:route" +
                    "?action=start" +
                    "&routeId=ftpRoute");

    from([ftpurl])
            .noAutoStartup()
            .routeId("ftpRoute")
            .aggregate(constant(true), new FileAggregationStrategy())
            .completionFromBatchConsumer()
            .process(filesProcessor)
            .to("controlbus:route" +
                    "?action=stop" +
                    "&routeId=" + BESTANDEN_ROUTE_ID);
```

The issue at hand is that with this method the request does not wait for the complete process to finish, it almost instantly returns an empty response with StatusCode 200.

I've tried multiple solutions but they all fail in either of two ways: either the request gets a response even though the route hasn't finished yet OR the route gets stuck waiting for inflight exchanges at some point and waits for the 5 minute timeout to continue.

Thanks in advance for your advice and/or help!

Note: I'm working in a Spring Boot application (2.0.5) and Apache Camel (2.22.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Screwtape's answer i managed to get it working for my specific issue. A few adjustments were needed, here is a list of what you need:

- Add the option "sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true" to the ftp url
- In the AggregationStrategy add an `if (exchange == null)` clause
- In the clause set a property "finished" to `true`
- Wrap the pollEnrich with a loopDoWhile that checks the finished property

In its entirety it looks something like:

```
from("direct:ftp")
            .routeId("ftpRoute")
            .loopDoWhile(!finished)
                .pollEnrich("ftpurl...&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true", new FileAggregationStrategy())
                .choice()
                    .when(finished)
                        .process(filesProcessor)
                        .end()
            .end();
```

In the AggregationStrategy the aggregate method looks something like:

```
@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange currentExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    if (currentExchange == null)
        return init(newExchange);
    else {
        if (newExchange == null) {
            currentExchange.setProperty("finished", true);
            return currentExchange;
        }
        return update(currentExchange, newExchange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that your two routes are not connected. You are using the control bus to *start* the second route but it doesn't return the value back to the first route - it just completes, as you've noted.

What I think you need (I've not tested it) is something like:

```
from("direct:getAllFiles")
            .routeId("filesDirectId")
            .pollEnrich( [ftpurl], new FileAggregationStrategy() )
            .process( filesProcessor );
```

as this will synchronously consume your ftp consumer, and do the post processing and return the values to your rest route.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it really helped a lot, had to make some adjustments to get it actually working so i formulated my own answer for others to find. Again, thanks a lot!